# django : how to rename a record in the admin panel

Tags: django, copy, save, admin

In the admin panel, can you rename a record (eg CT33 in CT34 without CT33 erasing )?

for example in the admin panel, two buttons save and save as

Comment: Do you mean create a duplicate? Use a 'save as'.

Answer (score 1):

[ModelAdmin.save_as](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as)

> Set save_as to enable a “save as” feature on admin change forms.
>
> Normally, objects have three save options: “Save”, “Save and continue
>   editing” and “Save and add another”. If save_as is True, “Save and add
>   another” will be replaced by a “Save as” button.
>
> “Save as” means the object will be saved as a new object (with a new
>   ID), rather than the old object.
>
> By default, save_as is set to False.

Comment: I tried \django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_form.html but there is no save_as option ?

Comment: It's not html. No need to manipulate the template. `save_as = True` should go in ModelAdmin. It lives in admin.py. If you can't get it to work, than edit your question and add your admin.py code. Then I'll show you by example.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as ?

Comment: thanks you very much...It works. I have a "save_as" button. No, I did not read...

Comment: You are welcome. I asked because the first line of my answer doesn't really stand out as a link. If you had seen it, you wound't be editing html! ;). If you think this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.